# HTML fixed div with relative div

Tags: html

I am looking for two divs that look like this:

```
<div style="height:20px;" />
<div style="height:100%;" />
```

This gives me two divs, one with 20px height, and the other at 100% of the entire screen height, which puts a vertical scroll bar worth 20px. What I actually want is one to be 20px, and the other to be 100%-20px. I know that IE has calc() method, but isn't there a much easier way to do this that will work in all browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#div1 {
    height:20px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    left:0px;
} 
#div2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

maybe this is what you need..

**EDIT** sorry misread the title.. corrected :O how ever if you wish to have multiple div2 the you might need a structure like

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2" style="overflow:auto">[multiple div2 go here]</div>
```

Comment: i moved to absolute and resolved it like how you said. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way: Place the first div (20px) inside the second.

**EDIT:** Since my first answer is not an option for you, you can use scripting to resize the div on the fly. You can caclulate `document.height - 20px` and apply the result as the height of the "100%" div. CSS does not offer a way to do:

```
height: 100% - 20px
```

However, Javascript does:

(via jQuery:)

```
$( "#big_div" ).height( $( document ).height() - 20 );
```

Comment: that unfortunately isn't really an option, because I have many divs and some (the 20px one) needs to stay on the screen while the 100% one goes on and off or is replaced.

Comment: thanks. it's unfortunate that HTML cannot do this, as this is a very basic task for layout.

Comment: @automaton: Although this may be more of a political/religious preference, I differ with your opinion. HTML should be strictly for markup; CSS should be strictly for presentation; Javascript should be strictly for logic. Blurring the lines leads to muddy, unmaintainable code. A little snippet of Javascript, in this case, goes a long way.

Comment: it's an interesting opinion, but XAML markup you can do this with height="Auto", height="*".. it's definitely layout, which is what HTML/css is for, so the fact that you require logic by default negates the fact that HTML/css is able to do layout :)

Comment: @automaton: HTML/CSS does layout. Html/CSS/Javascript does _dynamic_ layout.

Comment: you just used the word dynamic to cover the shortcomings of the layout-definition language. i see what you did there.

Comment: @automaton: Then we're back to my original point. I don't think this is a shortcoming. The fact that XAML does things differently is not relevant. HTML once had things (horrible things) like `<blink>` and `<marquee>` that have now been removed. They are not markup; they imply functionality. Compartmentalization leads to cleaner code and enhanced maintainability. If a particular developer wishes to implement such functionality on a given site, the tools are available. But we shouldn't provide all possible options in the _markup_ just because someone might want them someday.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this out, adding a little sample text to your div, and got rid of the scroll bar simply by not giving the second div a height, and allowing the broswer (both IE and FF) to figure out for itself what hieght to give it.

However, given your comment to George, I think this may not be your fix either.  Perhaps you could post a little bit more of your code (or psuedo-code) to give at least one typical example of the second div being replaced.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible without any Javascript if you can provide a fixed width:

http://jsfiddle.net/mNNeq/47/

The following is an excellent resource to help you with positioning content:

http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/